# SQL Server update same column using different conversion without overwriting

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-update, sql-convert

I have a table `DATES` that looks like this:

| Id | TimeStamp | TimeStamp_UTC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-08-03 12:10:30 | 2021-08-03 12:10:30.000 |
| 2 | 2021-09-13 12:21:44 | NULL |
| 3 | 11/23/2021 1:30:56.511 PM | NULL |
| 4 | 11/23/2021 1:37:27.476 PM | NULL |

The column `TimeStamp` is of type `nvarchar` and `TimeStamp_UTC` of type `datetime`.

I want to convert the data from `TimeStamp` into the column `TimeStamp_UTC` by using just one query.

That implies using two `CONVERT` functions, one for the first two dates and a slightly different one for the last two.

The SQL statements to convert both types are shown here:

For the first two:

```
UPDATE DATES
SET [TimeStamp_UTC_JM] = (SELECT CONVERT(datetime, [TimeStamp], 20) 
WHERE LEN([TimeStamp]) IN (18, 19))
```

For the other two dates:

```
UPDATE DATES 
SET [TimeStamp_UTC_JM] = (SELECT CONVERT(datetime, [TimeStamp], 21) 
WHERE LEN([TimeStamp]) BETWEEN 23 AND 26)
```

Individually both updates work, but when running the second query the converted values of the first update disappear, so I would like to perform the update in just one step, without overwriting.

Comment: Read about TRY_CONVERT. You can do ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(.. first style), TRY_CONVERT(... second style)

Comment: I used the `ISNULL` function together with `TRY_CONVERT`, but according to `ISNULL` syntax just two parameters are specified, the expression to be checked (`TimeStamp_UTC` in my case) and the replacement value (the conversion function). Nevertheless, your idea helped me finding a solution for the problem, since using just one `CONVERT` function for both datetime cases works. Thanks @siggemannen!

Comment: I don't think you understood what i ment. The first agrument to ISNULL is the TRY_CONVERT call that tries the first style, and then second is the second TRY_CONVERT call that tries the second style. Since try_convert returns NULL on failures, you can do both styles with help of ISNULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run these two `UPDATE` statements after each other - check to ensure you're not overwriting any existing values in `Timestamp_UTC` in your `WHERE` clause:

```
-- update the first style of date/time formats
UPDATE dbo.Dates
SET [TimeStamp_UTC] = CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), [TimeStamp], 120) 
WHERE LEN([TimeStamp]) IN (18, 19)
  AND TimeStamp_UTC IS NULL;

-- update the second style of date/time formats
UPDATE dbo.Dates
SET [TimeStamp_UTC] = CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), [TimeStamp], 101) 
WHERE LEN([TimeStamp]) BETWEEN 23 AND 26
  AND TimeStamp_UTC IS NULL;
```

I had to also change the styles used for conversion - since you have 4-digit years, those have to be styles in the 100er range - and the second style you had doesn't exist in 4-digit years - but `style = 101` seems to work just fine.

I also used `DATETIME2(3)` as datatype, since this is recommended since the days of SQL Server **2008** - it has a better precision, uses less memory to store its values, and has a larger range of supported dates - basically nothing but **benefits** over using the old `DATETIME` datatype. I'd **strongly recommend** defining any new columns to store date and time with the `DATETIME2(n)` datatype and phase out `DATETIME`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked in my case was, as I said, using just one `CONVERT` function for both datetime cases:

```
UPDATE DATES
SET TimeStamp_UTC = (SELECT ISNULL(TimeStamp_UTC, CONVERT(datetime, [TimeStamp], 21)))
```